# How can I get camera world direction with webxr?

Tags: three.js, webvr, webxr

I would like to use `camera.getWorldDirection()` and access to the head-mounted display directions. I was able to do this with the previous webVR API. When I use the new `HelioWebXRPolyfill.js` from THREE, I am not able to receive current positions.

Comment: Camera on new webXR implementation seems to have no link to the actual headset view, it sits aside from it. If i get camera.rotation and I look around using my headset there is no change. I am also looking for an answer to this one?!

Comment: I am facing the same issue? Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that calling `renderer.xr.getCamera()` isn't fully copying the various camera member properties that `camera.getWorldDirection()` is expecting to find.   I'm not sure where this problem originates (perhaps the polyfill?), but you can get around it by computing direction yourself :

```
        let xrCamera = this.renderer.xr.getCamera(sceneCamera)
        let e = xrCamera.matrixWorld.elements
        let direction = new THREE.Vector3(-e[8], -e[9], -e[10]).normalize()
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a simple fix. Just parent a box to the camera and use the camera box in place of the camera.

```
camera.add( camerabox );
```

This doesn't work:

```
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
camera.getWorldDirection( direction );
```

This DOES work:

```
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
camerabox.getWorldDirection( direction );
```

Comment: Actually it does not work with FireFox WebXR devtools. By camerabox you meant attaching a Mesh with a BoxGeometry?

Answer (score 1):

According to the WebXR Device API, this should be done using the [XRViewerPose object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XRViewerPose).

This feature is only working using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

global variable

```
var cameraVector = new THREE.Vector3();  //define once and reuse it!
```

in your render loop

```
let xrCamera = renderer.xr.getCamera(camera);
xrCamera.getWorldDirection(cameraVector);
//heading vector for webXR camera now within cameraVector
```